# Regex to capture LaTeX comments

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex to find comment lines in LaTeX. I created the following example. The last regex does not work. Can I have a single regex for all of the cases?

Before:

```
\usepackage{test}%COMMENT1

TEXT
%COMMENT2
TEXT

Value is 10\%, this should not be removed. %COMMENT3

begin{tikz}[
important 1,
%COMMENT4
important 2, %COMMENT5
]

TEXT
%COMMENT 6

TEXT

Table: value1&value2\\%COMMENT7
```

After:

```
\usepackage{test}

TEXT
TEXT

Value is 10\%, this should not be removed.

begin{tikz}[
important 1,
important 2,
]

TEXT

TEXT

Table: value1&value2\\
```

The is what I reached so far:

> (^%(.*?)\r?\n)

Works for comment 2,4,6 when replaced with nothing

> ([\]{2}%(.*?)\r\n)

This works for comment 7 when replaced with \\\r\n

> ([^\]%(.*?)\r?\n)

This does NOT work for comment 1 because it select the '}'

Comment: What is the condition to remove a line break after a comment?

Comment: If there is anything but an empty line on the next line then  the line break should be removed.

Comment: Please try `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?m)(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)%.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?$))?", "")` (forgot about `\r?` before `$`)

Comment: Its working, can you please add it so i can select it as answer. (optional) if you please can put some comments on how it works because I don't get it

Comment: Please see below explanation, is it clearer now? Please let know what is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"(?m)(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)%.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?$))?", "")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3F%3C!%5C%5C%29%28%3F%3A%5C%5C%7B2%7D%29*%29%25.*%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn%28%3F!%5Cr%3F%24%29%29%3F&i=%5Cusepackage%7Btest%7D%25COMMENT1%0D%0A%0D%0ATEXT%0D%0A%25COMMENT2%0D%0ATEXT%0D%0A%0D%0AValue%20is%2010%5C%25%2C%20this%20should%20not%20be%20removed.%20%25COMMENT3%0D%0A%0D%0Abegin%7Btikz%7D%5B%0D%0Aimportant%201%2C%0D%0A%25COMMENT4%0D%0Aimportant%202%2C%20%25COMMENT5%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0ATEXT%0D%0A%25COMMENT%206%0D%0A%0D%0ATEXT%0D%0A%0D%0ATable%3A%20value1%26value2%5C%5C%25COMMENT7&r=)

**Details**

- `(?m)` - `RegexOptions.Multiline` inline option, `$` will match before a newline, too.
- `(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)` - any even amount of backslashes, it is a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with `\` and then any 0 or more repetitions of double backslashes
- `%` - a `%` sign
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than an LF as many as possible
- `(?:\r?\n(?!\r?$))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `\r?\n` - an optional CR and then LF...
  - `(?!\r?$)` - not immediately followed with an optional CR and end of a line.

Comment: Just in case: `(?:\r?\n(?!\r?$))?` matches a line break sequence if it is not followed with an empty line. If there can be *blank* lines, you may use `(?!\s*$)` instead of `(?!\r?$)`.