# How should I use sublime text regex engine (PCRE) to delete all latex comments?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I followed the question in another post: [Regex to capture LaTeX comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726344/regex-to-capture-latex-comments)

The provided answer is awesome. However, it seems like it can only be used in the .net engine, but I want to use the PCRE engine. That is because  I'm using sublime text and it seems like this engine is used by default. I tried many times, but without success.

The latex is

```
\usepackage{test}%COMMENT1

TEXT
%COMMENT2
TEXT

Value is 10\%, this should not be removed. %COMMENT3

begin{tikz}[
important 1,
%COMMENT4
important 2, %COMMENT5
]

TEXT
%COMMENT 6

TEXT

Table: value1&value2\\%COMMENT7
Table: value1&value2\\      %COMMENT8
Table: value1&value2            \\%COMMENT 9
Table: value1&value2\\%            COMMENT 10
Table: value1&value2\\%COMMENT11
```

I tried `(?m)(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{0}))%.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?$))?`. Only works on comment 1-6,8.

The online results can be found https://regex101.com/r/zSIBMu/3

How should I modify it?

Comment: Do you also want to remove `\\\%COMMENT` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Probably not. Because "\\" will start a new line and '\%' will print out '%' itself. So, this is not a comment in latex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sublime text 2 how to delete comments only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572917/4473405)

Comment: @KeithHall Thanks a lot. I never thought of it in this way. This is pretty useful and can be used for all types of comments without using any new regex. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also make use of a [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) approach:

```
\\(?<!\\.)(?>\\\\)*%(*SKIP)(*F)|%.*
```

The pattern matches:

- `\\(?<!\\.)` Match `\` not preceded with `\`
- `(?>\\\\)*` Match optional pairs of `\\`
- `%(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Match `%` and skip the match
- `|` Or
- `%.*` Match `%` and the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1JlouD/1)

**Edit**

A non lookaround solution suggested by [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) to skip the match for `\\` or `\%`

```
\\[\\%](*SKIP)(*F)|%.*
```

- `\\[\\%]` Match either `\\` or `\%` using a character class
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Skip the match
- `|` Or
- `%.*` Match `%` and the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IO9Dnx/1)

Comment: If I were you, for a SKIP/FAIL approach with two branches, I will write something like `\\\\(*SKIP)(*F)|%.*` that blindly skips all escaped backslash whatever the location. (less complicated, and the two branches start with a literal string too.)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I started with an easier approach, but `\\\\(*SKIP)(*F)|%.*` will still have a match in `\%, this should not be removed. %COMMENT3`

Comment: You are right, but I'm sure there's something more simple to do (avoiding lookarounds).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Let me fiddle around with it a bit more, your feedback is appreciated :-)

Comment: Perhaps this one, but I'm not sure: https://regex101.com/r/eDGQjR/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I think a fuse just popped in my head, that looks beautiful. Can I add it, or do you want to add it to your answer?

Comment: No, It's for you, you rightly suggested the SKIP/FAIL approach.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Brilliant, thanks! I have read a lot of your answers (and still do), always a good read :-)

Comment: Thanks, but don't read too old answers (especially some that I haven't edited yet <°)))))>).

Answer (score 4):

With a capture group:

```
((?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)%.*
```

and with `$1` as replacement.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/AzcMS8/1)

Or perhaps, if `\K` is supported:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\K%.*
```

with an empty string as replacement.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/8dupWB/1)

Notice: I don't see any reason to remove the newline sequence even if the comment takes all the line.

Comment: Thanks. This is working. But I'm not sure if I understand the meaning of your notice.

Comment: @whatsname: That means that if a comment is at the start of the line, the replacement doesn't delete the line (only the comment).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think this is needed when there are multiple consecutive single lines of comments. Then, deleting them would make it look better than replacing them with white space.